# Anchor tag to some element in same page id doesn't work

Tags: html, anchor, anchor-scroll

Haai. I have a trouble in my little project. I've create `<a href="slogannya">some icon</a>` and `<blockquote id="slogannya">`but when I click the `<a>` tag it doesn't work. Here is my code :

Html

```
<section class="to-content">
        <a class="scrollTo" href="#slogannya">
          <button type="button">
            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
          </button>
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="slogan">
        <blockquote id="slogannya">
          <p>Wanna create an event? <br> or you want to give some advice to us? Use the form below </p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this).attr('href');
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
      }, 2000);
  });

});
```

How can I made this work? Please help me :)

**EDIT**

I know what my problems is. In my project, I have a css called 'general.css' (this css content css reset and other styling for any page). In this css, it makes any element to be `box-sizing: border-box;` and others style. I don't know specifically what the problems. But when I remove my 'general.css', the smooth scroll is work. Thank you for all your answers friends :) , I'm appreciate it!!

Comment: You can get this working without jQuery at all. Just define <a name="somename"></a> at some point of your page and then link to it <a href="thispage.html#somename">This way</a>, changing "thispage.html" to the name of your page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is HTML some `<a>`nchors and any element you want (even more `<a>`nchors go crazy). **BTW the reason targeting id wasn't working for you is because the `href` requires a prefix of `#` to the url. ex. `<a href="#ID"...`** Another reason that it may not work is that the `<a>`nchor and the destination element are too close to each other, so ideally a destination should be at least far enough that scrolling is needed to get there.

- For a destination element, ensure that it has an `#id`. ex `<div id='ID'...`
- Next, for each destination, create one or more `<a>`nchors and set their `href` values as `#`+ID. ex. `<a href='#ID...`
- If the destination element happens to be an `<a>`nchor, we can use the `name` attribute as well. ex. `<a name='NAME'...`

### Demo

```css
main {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

a[name] {
  background: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>
  <header>
    <h1>Anchor Test</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href='#s0'>Section 1</a>
      <a href='#s1'>Section 2</a>
      <a href='#s2'>Section 3</a>
    </nav>
    <nav id='toTop'>
      <a href='#end'>End </a>
      <a href='#a0'>Two-handed Weapon</a>
      <a href='#a1'>Cheapskates</a>
      <a href='#a2'>Devil Dance</a>
    </nav>

  </header>
  <hr>
  <section id='s0'>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>

    <p>Base save bonus checked cold dangers cold domain compulsion subschool constrict current hit points dead diminutive domain spell flank gargantuan hit hit die improved grab knocked down manufactured weapons movement modes negative energy plane off hand
      psionics result skill points spell version threat total cover transitive plane turn resistance turn undead undeath domain. Angel subtype caster level concealment continuous damage death domain energy drained extraplanar subtype guardinal subtype
      improved evasion lethal damage medium melee attack pounce rake subject <a name='a0'>two-handed weapon</a> undead type.</p>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section id='s1'>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>And it better be long as the troubles in my head hammer my bones on the anvil of daylight i'd buy some time i'm so tired don't know where to begin into your brother's cup just to see the dogs runnin on a blackboard night ringin' in my ears the information
      is ravenous you're acting like it's chill, when the deal's getting. And all the toilets are overflowing and i'm falling out of the conversation and the band playin' down below are those dogs or are those dogmas? black can spell to be day in the
      club tonight doldrums are pounding, <a name='a1'>cheapskates</a> are clowning this town flap your wings and leap out the window how do you play? she doesn't even know it's wrong she's the sister of avarice sipping the golden days on a riptide snooty.
      some static is lulling me to sleep talkin' to the devil and drinkin' a coke the dishes wash good to meet you in that land try not to drown where can you duck when they shoot you full of pigeon holes who are you? you said go.</p>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section id='s2'>
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. boys will be boys. curiosity killed the cat. cut your coat according to your cloth. do not bite the hand that feeds you. do not change horses in midstream. first impressions are the most lasting. he who hesitates
      is lost. if at first you do not succeed, try, try again. it is best to be on the safe side. kindness in words creates confidence. kindness in thinking creates profoundness. kindness in giving creates love. let the buyer beware. let your hair down.
      lightning never strikes twice in the same place. money makes many things, but also makes <a name='a2'>devil dance</a>. never speak ill of the dead. one might as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb. penny wise and pound foolish. practice makes perfect.
      silence is golden. talk is cheap. the grass is always greener on the other side of the fence. the road to hell is paved with good intentions. there is no accounting for tastes. third time is a charm. to the victor go the spoils. walnuts and pears
      you plant for your heirs. you cannot make an omelette without breaking eggs..</p>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <a href='#s0'>Section 1</a>
    <a href='#s1'>Section 2</a>
    <a href='#s2'>Section 3</a>
  </nav>
  <nav id='end'>
    <a href='#main'>Top </a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: hey, how to make this work on dynamically generated elements?

Comment: It should work fine since there's no need to bind any event handlers. I guess one caveat dealing with dynamically added elements is you'd have to know about them because this technique requires a predefined `#id` or `[name]` unless you are assigning those on the fly (which is very possible).

Comment: Well, I tried with dynamically added element, it worked when I added an anchor tag which needs to be clicked. But I want something different. I have a calender in page other than the element which needs to be shown. So when I click on an event on the calender, this `location.href = "/property/#id"` doesnt work for dynmically added elements, but works on static element.

Comment: *"But I want something different."* Different from an `<a>`? Different pair of shoes?  JK

Comment: It has been literally described after "But I want something different'. You need a different pair of eyes.

Comment: Ohh, I need a pair of humor. Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72443315/redirect-to-dynamically-generated-element-using-page-htmlid

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works but the problem is that  the blockquote tag are immediate after the anchor tag but if you make a space between them you'll see the animation in action

in brief : the animation will work only when the scroll bar appear on the window and there is a space between the two elements 
look at the example below and you'll see it works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".scrollTo").on('click', function (e) {
console.log('clicked');
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this).attr('href');
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top)
      }, 2000);
  });

});
```

```css
.any{
height:400px ;
width : 100% ; 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="to-content">
        <a class="scrollTo" href="#slogannya">
          <button type="button">
            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
         
          </button>
        </a>
      </section>
      <div class='any'></div>
      <section class="slogan">
        <blockquote id="slogannya">
          <p>Wanna create an event? <br> or you want to give some advice to us? Use the form below </p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was working but the code supplied had no height to scroll, also wasn't a smooth scroll. If that isn't the case try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1500, function() {

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.to-content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="to-content">
  <a href="#slogannya">
    <button type="button">
            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
          </button>
  </a>
</section>
<section class="slogan">
  <blockquote id="slogannya">
    <p>Wanna create an event? <br> or you want to give some advice to us? Use the form below </p>
  </blockquote>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't know why. But when I try your code, it doesn't work on my project :(

Comment: A few things to check. Do you have jQuery added to your site (above all other scripts)? In the inspect console, do you have any errors? Perhaps lastly, do you have the `section` `ID` below the page fold? If the `blockquote` is within the fold the page may not have any room to scroll.

Comment: Perhaps, if you try removing the `script` does the page goto the `blockquote` without scroll?

Comment: Just so we don't flood the comments, we can start a live chat and I can walk you through finding the issue. Just let me know.