# Why does my html/css navigationbar not jump to the given classes?

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

So I have created a simple one-page personal website with several elements; "Home", "About Me", "CV" and "Contact". And I have implemented it all in my navigationbar classes. However, when I use the navigationbar it will not jump to to the class I selected! Can anyone solve this?

The Code Sample I used (Some is in Dutch):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
             aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">CV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header id="home" class="home">
    <div class="overlay sections">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                        <div class="home-details text-center">

                            <div class="logo">
                                <img src="assets/img/Logo.png" alt="Logo" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="home-title">
                                <h1><span>TIM</span>DIJKSTRA</h1>
                            </div>

                            <div class="scroll-down">
                                <h5>Scroll naar beneden voor meer!</h5>
                                <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section id="about" name="about" class="about sections">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="about-photo">
                        <img src="assets/img/Tim.png" alt="Tim Dijkstra" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="heading about-content">
                        <h3>About Me</h3>
                        <p>Hoi, ik ben Tim!</p>
                        <p>Een gedreven student met een passie voor alles wat software is. Sinds mijn jeugdjaren ben ik al
                            geïnteresseerd in het ontwikkelen van applicaties. Het was dan ook een logische stap om deze hobby door te
                            zetten tot mijn huidige studie, Software Ontwikkeling op de Avans University of Applied Sciences in
                            's-Hertogenbosch. Sindsdien heb ik gewerkt met verschillende programmeertalen en frameworks, zoals Java, SQL,
                            C#, HTML/CSS, PHP, Python en meer.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="scroll-down">
            <h6>Blijf scrollen, er is nog meer te zien!</h6>
            <a href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="overlay sections">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="heading text-center">
                <div class="title">

                    <h3>CV</h3>

                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <div class="portfolio-details">

                            <a href="assets/doc/CV.pdf" target="_blank">
                                <img src="assets/img/CV.png" />
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="scroll-down">
                        <h5>Blijf scrollen, er is nog meer te zien!</h5>
                        <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="contact" class="contact sections">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="contact-details text-center">

                    <div class="contact-category">
                        <div class="mail">
                            <h5>Mail :</h5>
                            <h2><a href="mailto:contact@timdijkstra.info">contact@timdijkstra.info</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contact-category">
                        <div class="linkedin">
                            <h5>LinkedIn :</h5>
                            <h2><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/timdijkstra/" target="_blank">www.linkedin.com/in/timdijkstra</a></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer id="footer" class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="copyright text-center">
                    <p>Website made by Tim Dijkstra. All rights reserved.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033946/anchor-tag-to-some-element-in-same-page-id-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

You want to click an a-tag and then the current view should move to the tag with that id specified in the href don't you?

For me it actually **does** work with your code.

Check out this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPjbaQ

Since linking anchors and ids is a [html specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1) this is everything you need:

```
<a href="myCustomAnchor">Click me to move to 'myCustomAnchor'</a>

<section id="myCustomAnchor">Some Content .... </div>
```