# redirect to dynamically generated element using "page.html#id"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalender on a page which displays events for the payment due. On clicking the event (`eventClick: function(){}`) the code leads to a page where the payment are shown and highlight the particular payment.

```
function highlightCard(info) {

    let prop_id = info.event._def.publicId
    sessionStorage.setItem("prop-id", prop_id)
    location.href = '/property/#pay-cards'
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $($($('#pay-cards').find('#pay-col-0')).find('.pay-card')).css('border', '0.2em solid blue')
    })
}

calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    expandRows: true,
    height: 'auto',
    stickyHeaderDates: true,

    customButtons: {
        addEvent: {
            text: 'Add Event',
            click: function () {
                $('#AddEventModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    },

    eventClick: function (info) {
        if (info.event._def.publicId != '') {
            highlightCard(info)
        }
    },

    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'addEvent,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
    },

    locale: initialLocaleCode,
    direction: 'rtl',
    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    eventDidMount: function (info) {
        $(info.el).tooltip({
            title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
            placement: "top",
            trigger: "hover",
            container: "body"
        });
    },

    events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        successCallback(data);
    },
});

calendar.render();
```

The page where the click event leads to is

```
<div class="row g-0 gy-5 mt-5 pb-5 pay-card-row" id="pay-cards">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 d-flex justify-content-center" id="pay-col-0" data-sid="1">
        <div class="pay-card dropup" style="border: 0.2em solid blue;">
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">
                <div class="property-info">
                    <p id="card-pay-name">Bottle</p>
                </div>
                <div class="option-btn-1 dropend"><a href="" class="" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><button class="drop-btn" id="pay-card-delete"
                                onclick="deletePaymentCard()">Delete</button></li>
                        <li><button class="drop-btn" id="pay-card-edit">Edit</button></li>
                        <li><button class="drop-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalReminder"
                                id="pay-card-reminder">Reminder</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card2-body text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalNotePayment"
                id="notes-modal">
                <div id="ex4"><span class="p1 fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" data-count="17"><i class="fa-solid fa-bell"
                            data-count="4b"></i></span></div>
                <p class="card-text" id="card-pay-amount" aria-label="card-pay-amount-income"
                    style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">450₪</p>
                <p class="card-text" id="card-pay-cycle">Every 4 Days</p>
                <p class="card-text" id="card-pay-date">12/05/22 - 15/07/22</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are two problems in here. First is in the `highlightcard()` ==> `location.href = /products/#pay-cards/` works, but I want to lead to specific card like `location.href = /products/#pay-col-0/` but as the element is dynamically generated it doesnt work. 2nd problem is the card is not highlighted that is no border is added. I know the code inside the `highlightcard()` is not a proper code, the usage of `$(document).ready()` is also not a proper way. How to solve this two problem?

Comment: `location.href =` will unload the page and load a *new* page, any js on the old page will be "thrown away" and reset - so your doc.ready will not run "on the new page" (which is what it looks like you're attempting).   You'll need a doc.ready that checks for the sessionStorage.   If it helps, completely separate the js - have a `page1.js` and a `page2.js` - only include page1 on page1 (etc) so any js in page1 will not run on page2.

Comment: I dont quite follow the `doc.ready` to check for the `sessionStorage` but are you suggesting that I should move the highlight card function on other javascript file?

Comment: Whatever happens on page1 goes in script1, whatever happens on page2 goes in script2.  If you're trying to highlight a card on page2, then the script needs to be in script2.js.  This will allow you to separate (in your mind) which code is running when.   So `location.href=` runs on page1, then, when page2 has loaded, it runs script2 - so the code to set the card on page2 can't be directly after `location.href =`

Comment: can I add a promise object, which will resolve when the page2 is fully loaded and then the highlight card script is executed. BTW I have not used promise objects, I just have the idea about it. Do you about this? Because your idea to separate js wont work in my structure. I use Django and have created a base template where all the static files are loaded. So According to it each page has all the static files in the project.

Comment: A promise is a javascript object, so... no.   All javascript is reset.  You *can* use `sessionStorage` which is what this is for